# iconfonts only show in Chrome on hover

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am using Bootstrap glyphicons and FontAwesome icons and am experiencing a strange bug where they do not show unless hovered over, at which point they are permanently visible. When I reload the page they aren't visible again.

This only happens in Chrome. Safari and Firefox both show the icons normally.

I am running Chrome v33.0.1750 - this has never happened before.

Comment: Tried replicating your problem on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: As this question currently formed is a bit unclear.. so unless you'll provide more data like @SonuJoshi for example mentioned.. this question will be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. Turns out there's a conflict with one the jQuery plugins, holder.js - the image placeholder plugin. Removed that and the icons show fine now on reload.

Strange, considering that in Bootstrap's documentation, they use holder.js to generate images for their 'Thumbnails' section.

**UPDATE:**

It seems there is a conflict between Chrome 33 and any version of holder.js above v1.9.

https://github.com/imsky/holder/issues/81?codekitCB=415695904.557899

Answer (score 1):

I found some JavaScript code to re draw the page and works for me. I found this on SO somewhere so it's not my code.

```
$(document).ready(function()    
{
    var Offset = $('body').offset();
    $('body').offset(Offset);
});
```